# Most adequate data type to store version number? Or workaround using a procedure?

Tags: mysql

Currently we have a datagrid ( php ) to store the code and version number of some deployed codes, but i'm facing some problems regarding what data type should i use to store the version number.

I was thinking about creating 3 fields (tinyint maybe) named major,minor and revision, But this would give me some problems regarding on the datagrid because we want the users to insert only the full version number

ex:

```
 Insert version : 1.10.1
```

And not something like that:

```
Insert major : 1
Insert minor : 10
Insert rev.  : 1
```

So, what datatype should i use to store version? Or it's a good idea to create a procedure to split the inputs of the version into 3 fields?

EDIT: The main reason i need to split the values, is because before each deployment to production i need to query the code by the most recent version.

Comment: It is a very good idea to create a procedure to split the inputs.  But you could also use default inputs (such as have the user enter the Major, with pull-downs for minor and rev.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by  using this simple solution:

Adding the following fields:

```
 major
 minor
```

And creating the two triggers:

Insert :

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `insert`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `version_test`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
         set new.major = SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.code_version,'.',1),
             new.minor = SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.code_version,'.',-1);
 END
```

Update:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `update`
 BEFORE UPDATE ON `version_test`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN 
      SET new.major=SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.code_version,'.',1),
          new.minor=SUBSTRING_INDEX(new.code_version,'.',-1);
 END
```

I really hope this help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Store each part in it's own column as (tiny)integers:

```
version
-------
major
minor
patch
build
```

This will make it easy to sort and concatenate when called.

You can have a composite key or create a surrogate key if it will be referenced by other tables.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but we dont want to rework all the datagrid pages to split the version field into 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

As you aren't going to be performing any calculations on it, there is not need to store it as an integer. A simple string field would do.

Also, if you ever have a version like 1.2a it will also fit in the same field.

You can use [`strtok`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to split it up into its various components.